# True for all characters of a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python 3, what's the shortest way to check whether a predicate is true for all characters of a string?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
all(predicate(x) for x in string)
```

Comment: ...and it's not only the shortest but the most efficient one, because a) it's using a generator and b) `all()` short-circuits, so the iteration stops at the first `False` predicate.

Answer (score 2):

```
all(map(predicate, string))
```

Functionally the same as @Abe's answer but with map instead (also lazy in python3)

Comment: A disadvantage of this approach is if `predicate(x)` is something like `x[0]`, in which case either a lambda or the operator module is needed to use map.

Comment: Agree, you have the disadvantage of this (adding 8 letters) when predicate isn't callable, but you have the advantage of replacing map with an lazy parallel implementation of map (or any other implementation) if for example predicate is computationally heavy.